# Display Selected Option Color - AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, font-awesome

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the selected option color to display after the user selects an option?

In this example I'm using the Unicode flag character from the Font-Awesome library.

This code is running in an AngularJS application but is this something that can just as easily be handled with CSS.

```
<label for="followUp">FollowUp:</label>
<select  id="followUp" class="fa  fa-flag" style="font-family:'FontAwesome',Arial;">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option class="fa  fa-flag" style="color:blue;" value="1">&#xf024;</option>
     <option class="fa  fa-flag" style="color:violet;" value="2">&#xf024;</option>
    <option class="fa  fa-flag" style="color:yellow;" value="3">&#xf024;</option>
    <option class="fa  fa-flag" style="color:red;" value="4">&#xf024;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Angular data binding can be helpful here.

Comment: Angular data (ng-model) means I need to use some sort of value to color cross reference and I suppose a switch statement to set the ng-style of the select.  I'm hopping there is a way to get the CSS color of the option and then pass that to the ng-style but so far I've been unable to figure out how to get to the option object from ng-change.

Comment: ng-class may be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this:

In your controller, you can define a scope variable to store the mapping for the different colors and the values.

```
$scope.styleOptions = {"1":"blue","2":"violet","3":"yellow","4":"red"};
```

Change your HTML like this:

```
<label for="followUp">FollowUp:</label>
<select id="followUp" ng-model="selectedValue"
    ng-class="styleOptions[selectedValue]">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option class="fa  fa-flag blue" value="1">One &#xf024;</option>
   <option class="fa  fa-flag violet" value="2">Two &#xf024;</option>
   <option class="fa  fa-flag yellow" value="3">Three &#xf024;</option>
   <option class="fa  fa-flag red" value="4">Four &#xf024;</option>
</select>
```

I added One, Two.. in options just to see the color being changed after selection.

Here is the plnkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/0dPX0Mi5VvliILAs5QJQ)

Comment: This solution means I need to create an array which links value to color.  I was hoping there was a way to read the color value of the selected option and then apply it through ng-style or ng-class.  The idea here being the data that fills the option values will not always be a simple 1,2,3... but the sequence of flags will remain static.  Any ideas how to get to the selected option object where the css color is already set?

Comment: It is normally the case that that option values come from the back end, simple or complex. That is, they are usually driven by data. If that is the case, then this approach is simple.